# Replace string or normalize variable in serverless framework

Tags: string, serverless, serverless-framework

serverless recommends service name in string-string format, but this contains dash character, which is not allowed in some resource names, e.g. iot rule name.

What could be solution to replace dash with underscore character, or similar like:

```
custom:
  service_name_normalized: ${(${self:service}).replace('-','_')}
```

this is concept string, it does not work. Usage of `${self:custom.service_name_normalized}` results in literal string.

Answer (score 2):

**AWS**
You can make use of [intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html).

In this case (substitution of '-' with '_'), I would suggest you to use a combination of [Fn::Split](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-split.html) and [Fn::Join](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html).

`service_name_normalized: ${(${self:service}).replace('-','_')}`

equals

`service_name_normalized: !Join [ '_', !Split [ '-', '${self:service}' ] ]`

The `Fn::Split` function returns a list of strings, which the `Fn::Join` function receives as second argument.

Comment: will try that out in few sprints and if it will work, will accept the answer.

Comment: Doesn't work for me (trying to use with SSM). a `serverless print` does seem to convert it all to `Fn::Join`/`Fn::Split` functions, but I'm guess they only actually get executed at some later point in time, after it's already tried to use the result for an SSM lookup and failing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm personally not aware of such functionality, but it's possible to write a plugin that will introduce new utils/functions that can be used in your configuration file, you can look for inspiration here: https://github.com/whardier/serverless-plugin-powertools. I guess a functionality like the one you need could fit nicely into that plugin as well.

As an alternative, you can switch from `yml`-based configuration to JS/TS based one. You will then have full power of JS/TS when writing and processing your configuration.